# Reference type in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement documentreference in firestore. I created two collections : `Customers` and `Purchased-Property`. How can i reference the `Customer_id` in the `Purchased-Property_Customer_id`  everytime a new document is created in the `Purchased-Property` collection.
The code is shown below:

```
 const CustomerDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("Customers").doc()
CustomerDoc.set({
       Customer_id: CustomerDoc.id,
       Customer_Name: Name
       Customer_PhoneNumber: PhoneNumber

    })

const PurchasedPropertyDoc = firebase.firestore().collection("Purchased-Property").doc()
    PurchasedPropertyDoc.set({
           Purchased_Property_id: PurchasedPropertyDoc.id,
           Purchased_Property_Name: Property_Name,
           Purchased_Property_Location: Property_Location,
           Purchased_Property_Customer_Id: Customer_Id   //How do i make  reference to this Customer_Id in the Customers collection everytime a new document under the Purchased-Property collection is made 


    
        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CustomerDoc` is a [DocumentReference](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/documentreference) object.  Every DocumentReference has an `id` property.  You can simply use it like this:

```
    PurchasedPropertyDoc.set({
           Purchased_Property_id: PurchasedPropertyDoc.id,
           Purchased_Property_Name: Property_Name,
           Purchased_Property_Location: Property_Location,
           Purchased_Property_Customer_Id: CustomerDoc.id
    })
```

It's no different than the way you first used `CustomerDoc.id` in your first document.  If you don't have this reference available at the time you create the document, then you won't be able to make the association.

Comment: How then can i use the reference data type for easier location of the `Customer_Id` since the answer above, which is correct, store it as a string

Comment: Using a reference type isn't necessarily any easier.  You still have to make a query for the other document.  But you can just pass `CustomerDoc` directly if you want a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ref like:

```
const CustomerRef = db.collection( "users" ).doc( userId )
```

and then set as `Purchased_Property_Customer_Id:CustomerRef`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.